# Getting a unexpected link in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm practicing a simple blog site, where if I clicked in author names, it shows the associated post! If I used two different view function the output is fine but if I implemented in one function, in author's post page it shows a url which should not! The screenshot of the html page:

[image]

The **Url Link** contain author post page link! but according to the code it should display the post link!

```
<a href="{{ post.url }}">Url Link</a>
```

I'm pasting my all code for better understanding. Thanks in advance!

This is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('^$', views.url_list, name='url_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$',
        views.post_details, name = 'post_links'),
    # url(r'^author/(?P<author_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.author_posts, name = 'url_list_by_author'),
    url(r'^author/(?P<author_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.post_details, name = 'url_list_by_author'),
]
```

and my view.py is:

```
def post_details(request, year=None, month=None, day=None, post=None, author_slug=None):
    author_post_list = None
    if year:
        post = get_object_or_404(UrlPost, slug=post,
                                            status='published',
                                            publish__year=year,
                                            publish__month=month,
                                            publish__day=day,
        )
    if author_slug:
        author_post_list = UrlPost.author_manager.author_post(author_slug)
        post = None
    return render(request, 'detail.html', {'post': post, 'author_post_list': author_post_list})
```

and html page:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}{{post.title}}{% endblock  %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ post.title|title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ post.publish }}</p>
    <ul>
        {% for author in post.author.all %}
            {% if forloop.first %}
                <li><h4>Author: &nbsp;</h4></li>
            {% endif %}
            <li><h4><a href="{% url "blog:url_list_by_author" author %}">{{ author|title }}</a></h4></li>
            {% if not forloop.last %}
                <li><h4>, &nbsp;</h4></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <p>{{ post.description }}</p>
    <a href="{{ post.url }}">Url Link</a>
    {% include "author_post.html" %}
{% endblock  %}
```

Comment: What's in base.html?

Comment: `{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock  %}</title>
        <link href="{% static "css/blog.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="main_content">
            {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
            </div>
            <div id="sidebar">
                <h3>This is UrlCollection Site</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>`

Comment: The template you posted does not match the rendered content. Either you posted the wrong template by mistake, or this is the actual cause of your problem.

Comment: I am pretty much sure this is may base.html! if you want to see the author_post.html template, this is:
`{% block content %}
    {% for post in author_post_list %}
    <h2><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title|title }}</a></h2>
    <a href="{{ post.url }}">Url Link</a>
    <p>{{post.publish}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    <h4>Hello</h4>
{% endblock  %}`

Answer (score 0):

The first 'url link' you see at the top comes from this line in your html template:

```
<a href="{{ post.url }}">Url Link</a>
```

All the rest of what is displayed comes from the `author_post.html` template. The url link is not "additional", actually it's just that everything before is missing.

Probably because the `post` variable is `None`. If you actually inspect the generated html, it will look like this:

```
<h1></h1>
<p></p>
<ul>
</ul>
<p></p>
<a href="">Url Link</a>
(and the here you will have the contents of author_post)
```

OK, now for how to solve this: you should not use the same view to display the post and the post author's post. You should create two separate views. Each with its template. Then, assuming you named the new view `author_posts` in your `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('^$', views.url_list, name='url_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$',
        views.post_details, name = 'post_links'),
    url(r'^author/(?P<author_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.author_posts, name = 'url_list_by_author'),
]
```

Comment: I already solved it by implementing two views, I just need to know why the reason! Thank u, I now get why **Url Link** shows. But another thing is my post variable is None so

Comment: I already solved it by implementing two views, I just need to know why the reason! Thank u, I now get why Url Link shows. But another thing is my post variable is None so 
`<a href="{{ post.url }}">Url Link</a>`
here it should translate into this : {{ None:url }}
Then why I'm getting link in this like:
[http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/author/mohib] ?